# If I want to give more work to my Process Pool, can I call Pool.join() before Pool.close()?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

The documentation for `multiprocessing` [states](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.join) the following about `Pool.join()`:

> Wait for the worker processes to exit. One must call `close()` or `terminate()` before using `join()`.

I know that `Pool.close()` prevents any other task from being submitted to the pool; and that `Pool.join()` waits for the pool to finish before proceeding with the parent process.

So, why can I not call `Pool.join()` before `Pool.close()` in the case when I want to reuse my pool for performing multiple tasks and then finally `close()` it much later? For example:

```py
pool = Pool()
pool.map(do1)
pool.join() # need to wait here for synchronization
.
.
.
pool.map(do2)
pool.join() # need to wait here again for synchronization
.
.
.
pool.map(do3)
pool.join() # need to wait here again for synchronization
pool.close()

# program ends
```

Why *must* one "call `close()` or `terminate()` before using `join()`"?

Comment: Why do you need to call any function on the pool at all? Just reuse it.

Answer (score 6):

> So, why can I not call `Pool.join()` before `Pool.close()`

Because [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join) waits for the workers to *exit*. Not just finish the tasks they've been given, but actually exit. If you didn't call `close()` beforehand, then no one had told the workers to exit and they are on stand-by, ready to accept further tasks.

So a call to `join()` not preceded by a call to `close()` would just hang - `join()` would wait forever for workers to exit, which no one told them to do. For this reason Python raises a `ValueError("pool is still running")` error if yopu attempt to do so.

As David Schwartz pointed out, don't call `join()` to "synchronize" - it doesn't serve that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You need not call `join()` after `map()` in your case, because `map()` call **blocks** until all results are done.

Call `join()` before `close()` or `terminate()` is incorrect. Because `join()` is a blocking call and wait for the worker processes **to exit**. Therefore you can not reuse pool after `join()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-use the pool without calling any special functions on it. There's nothing special you need to do to continue to send jobs to the pool. If you aren't completely done with it, just leave it alone and let it keep doing its thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it painfully obvious, you can use the following code to prove to yourself that the code is in fact synchronized regardless:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import datetime

def do_something(i):
    with open(f'{i}.txt', 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(str(i))
    time.sleep(5)


def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)

    print('Starting process', datetime.datetime.now())
    pool.map(do_something, range(5))
    print('Waiting for sync', datetime.datetime.now())
    pool.map(do_something, range(5, 10))
    print('Waiting for final sync', datetime.datetime.now())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You'll observe that

> Waiting for sync

is not printed until the first pool completes its assigned tasks. `Pool.join()` is specifically waiting for the worker processes to exit, not for them to synchronize. They don't run asynchronously in this configuration regardless and will sync up fine.