# How to perform on global dataframe in the target function of multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I have the following code. I want to calculate values of all pairs using **calculate_mi** function on global dataframe **df** with python multiprocess.

```
from multiprocess import Pool

def calculate_mi(pair):
  global df
  from pyitlib import discrete_random_variable as drv
  import numpy as np
  i, j = pair
  val = ( 2*drv.information_mutual(df[i].values.astype(np.int32), df[j].values.astype(np.int32)) ) / ( drv.entropy(df[i].values.astype(np.int32)) + drv.entropy(df[j].values.astype(np.int32)) )
  return (i,j), val

def calculate_value(t_df):
  global df
  df = t_df
  all_pair = [('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2')]

  pool = Pool()
  pair_value_list = pool.map(calculate_mi, all_pair)
  pool.close()
  print(pair_value_list)

def calc():
  data = {'1':[1, 0, 1, 1],
    '2':[0, 1, 1, 0],
    '3':[1, 1, 0, 1],
    '0':[0, 1, 0, 1] }

  t_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  calculate_value(t_df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  calc()
```

This code gives me the expected output in **google colab** platform. But it gives the following error while I run it in my Local machine. (I am using windows 10 ,anaconda, jupyter notebook,python 3.6.9). How can i solve this or is there another way to do it?
[RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last), ...  NameError: name 'df' is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q74Tl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a couple of things:

1. It should be: `from multiprocessing import Pool` (not `from multiprocess`)
2. It appears you have left out the import of the `pandas` library.

Moving on ...

The problem is that under Windows the creation of new processes is not done using a `fork` call and consequently the sub-processes do not automatically inherit global variables such as `df`. Therefore, you must initialize each sub-process to have global variable `df` properly initialized by using an initializer when you create the `Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

def calculate_mi(pair):
  global df
  from pyitlib import discrete_random_variable as drv
  import numpy as np
  i, j = pair
  val = ( 2*drv.information_mutual(df[i].values.astype(np.int32), df[j].values.astype(np.int32)) ) / ( drv.entropy(df[i].values.astype(np.int32)) + drv.entropy(df[j].values.astype(np.int32)) )
  return (i,j), val

# initialize global variable df for each sub-process
def initpool(t_df):
    global df
    df = t_df

def calculate_value(t_df):
  all_pair = [('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2')]

  # make sure each sub-process has global variable df properly initialized:    
  pool = Pool(initializer=initpool, initargs=(t_df,))
  pair_value_list = pool.map(calculate_mi, all_pair)
  pool.close()
  print(pair_value_list)

def calc():
  data = {'1':[1, 0, 1, 1],
    '2':[0, 1, 1, 0],
    '3':[1, 1, 0, 1],
    '0':[0, 1, 0, 1] }

  t_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  calculate_value(t_df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  calc()
```

Comment: As far I know, Ipython jupyter notebook does not support  `multiprocessing` till now. But it supports `mutiprocess` module which is a fork of  [multiprocessing] (https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/), that's why I used it as I am working with jupyter notebook.This piece of code works fine but if I use `numpy` ,`drv` 
 module outside of  `calculate_mi` function it gives error that is "name 'drv' is not defined". Is there any way to import this once outside the `calculate_mi` function and use it by all child process?[N.B. I had placed them in `initpool` method, it still shows the same error]

Comment: First, there is a [way to use `multiprocessing` in jupyter notebook](https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac). I've never had a problem with importing `numpy` globally using `multiprocessing`. If you are saying that is an issue with `multiprocess`, then switch to `multiprocessing` according to the link I've shown you or stop using jupyter notebook.

Comment: And as an aside: If you don't use a context manager, i.e. `with Pool(...) as pool:`, which terminates the pool correctly, then after you call `pool.close()`, you should really call `pool.join()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271547/when-should-we-call-multiprocessing-pool-join

Comment: What is the difference between `multiprocess` and `multiprocessing` module or is there any disadvantages of this module. Why do you suggest to use `multiprocessing` instead of `multiprocess`?

Comment: I am not familiar with `multiprocess` and when I went to the `PyPi` repository to look it up I could not learn very much from the description.. So I suggested what is the *standard* and what I know *should* work.