# ValueError: 'Pool not running' when trying to loop the multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, append, list-comprehension, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I'm trying to run the same pool three times so that it adds the values in the same list:

```
import multiprocessing

def foo(name,archive):
    print('hello ', name)
    archive.append(f"hello {name}")

def main():
    max_process = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1 or 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_process)
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

    archive = manager.list()

    arguments = ['home','away','draw']
    for _ in range(3):
        [pool.apply_async(foo, args=[name,archive]) for name in arguments]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    print(archive)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The first batch runs perfectly, but when the second batch goes, this error appears:

```
ValueError: Pool not running
```

How should I proceed to generate this looping?

Comment: you close the pool after the first iteration and then you try to join a closed pool. move the join to be above the close and move both of them out of the loop

Comment: Hi @Nullman if I put ```join``` above ```close```, this error appears → ```ValueError: Pool is still running``` but keeping ```close``` above ```join``` worked perfectly outside the loop. But is it wrong to use it this way?

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38271547/7540911) question and answers for more details

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I still have doubts, I saw the usefulness of ```join``` being called above ```close```, but for my case the error ```ValueError: Pool is still running``` keeps appearing whenever I try to use this way. I don't understand how I can solve this detail.

Comment: it seems like you need to do it the other way around with multiprocessing, call close first and then join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by Nullman in comments, the error was in keeping `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` inside the loop, bringing them out, worked perfectly:

```
import multiprocessing

def foo(name,archive):
    print('hello ', name)
    archive.append(f"hello {name}")

def main():
    max_process = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1 or 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_process)
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

    archive = manager.list()

    arguments = ['home','away','draw']
    for _ in range(3):
        [pool.apply_async(foo, args=[name,archive]) for name in arguments]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    
    print(archive)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Well, thats the sollution, but why even use join then if it can't be used inside loop for waiting for all processes