# All memory consumed by Python Process pool while processing video using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, asynchronous, video, multiprocessing

I am processing a video using opencv in python, wherein I have to do some processing on each frame of video, and keep storing the results of that processing that I did on that frame, so for that I first tried the normal sequential approach i.e.

- Read one frame at a time.
- Do processing on that frame, append the result to a list.
- Repeat.

But then I found that while I am processing a frame, I can read the next frame of the video in advance, so after giving it a thought, I arrived at this approach:

- Read a frame from video.
- Append the frame to a list i.e. `frames.append(frame)`, If the list size is 100, then append a job in the job queue using this: `jobs.append(ppool.apply_async(process_fun, (frames,)))`  and then empty the list for next batch of frames i.e. `frames=[]`.
- Repeat
- When done reading frames, wait for jobs to complete and then fetch their results

*(Here `process_fun` is the function that does processing on a batch of frames)*

Here is the complete code for that:

```
import cv2
import os
import random
import multiprocessing as mp


def process(frames):
    lower = 0
    upper = 30
    frames_len = len(frames)
    idx = 0
    black_counts = []
    while idx < frames_len:
        # cv2.imwrite('frame ' + str(idx) + ".jpg", frames[idx])
        frames[idx] = cv2.cvtColor(frames[idx], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        black_selected = cv2.inRange(frames[idx], lower, upper)
        black_count = cv2.countNonZero(black_selected)
        black_counts.append(black_count)
        idx += 1
    return black_counts


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ppool = mp.Pool(processes=os.cpu_count())

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../movie.mp4')

    total_frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    print("total_frames:", total_frames)

    # random_frame_start = random.randint(1, total_frames)
    # cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, random_frame_start)
    # print("random_frame_start: ", random_frame_start)
    # frames_to_read = 1500

    frames_to_read = total_frames
    frames = []
    jobs = []

    while frames_to_read >= 0:
        grabbed, frame = cap.read()
        if grabbed:
            frames.append(frame)
            frames_to_read -= 1
            if frames_to_read % 100 == 0:
                print("appending a job at frames_to_read:", frames_to_read)
                jobs.append(ppool.apply_async(
                    process, (frames,)))
                frames = []
    cap.release()

    ppool.close()
    ppool.join()

    results = []
    for job in jobs:
        results.append(job.get())

    print("results are:", results)
```

*The posted code reads all frames of some movie.mp4*.

But when I run this code for values of `frames_to_read` between 100 to 5000(using the commented code), it runs fine(although it still takes large amount of memory), but when I run for values of `frames_to_read` equal to `total_frames` it consumes my whole memory(8GB RAM and ALL OF SWAP) and the system hangs.

**So, my question is why is this code consuming so much memory that the system gets hanged and I have to forcefully(physically) switch it off ? The memory consumption on a single run of this code keeps increasing and never decreases.. why is this happening and how to solve it ? :)**

I found some other SO questions where people were having this same problem, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414020/memory-usage-keep-growing-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485319/high-memory-usage-using-python-multiprocessing), but neither of those solutions worked.

Comment: even i m facing the same issue, did you solve the issue??